# How to get vowels in Like operator of SQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, string, where-clause, sql-like

I was solving a problem on SQL from Hackerrank. I have to make a query such that it gives me all city names starting with a, e, i, o or u. I'm using Like operator but still wrong answer.

Here's the problem [Link](https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/weather-observation-station-6/problem)

Here's my solution-

```
SELECT DISTINCT CITY
FROM STATION
WHERE CITY LIKE '[AEIOU]%'
```

Can anybody explain?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`LIKE` does not support that parttern. You need a regular expression match for this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT CITY
FROM STATION
WHERE CITY REGEXP '^[AEIOU]'
```

In the regex, `^` represents the beginning of the string, and the square brackets define a custom character class (meaning that the first character must belong to that list).

On the other hand, if you were to use `LIKE`, you would need multiple conditions, which would make the code lengthier (and probably less efficient):

```
WHERE 
    CITY LIKE 'A%' 
    OR CITY LIKE 'E%' 
    OR CITY LIKE 'I%'
    OR CITY LIKE 'O%'
    OR CITY LIKE 'U%'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select distinct city from station where Left(city,1)='A' or Left(city,1)='E' or Left(city,1)='I' or Left(city,1)='O' or Left(city,1)='U';
```

This worked fine with me (MS SQL)

Answer (score 0):

SELECT DISTINCT CITY FROM STATION WHERE LEFT(CITY, 1) IN ('A', 'E', 'I', 'O', 'U');

This return the City names starting with vowel.